# how to extract z-values from clmm output summary

Tags: r

I am using `clmm()` function (from *ordinal* package) to run mixed effect ordinal logistic regression and need to extract the parameters for the `B estimate` for the `RMem` variable.

```
otp <- summary(clmm(Rank ~ RMem + (1|sbj.ID), data = brands))

> otp
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: as.factor(Rank) ~ RMem + (1 | sbj.ID)
data:    dataset

 link  threshold nobs logLik   AIC      niter       max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  1921 -5433.43 10908.87 5152(10419) 1.02e-02 1.2e+03

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 sbj.ID (Intercept) 0.04227  0.2056  
Number of groups:  sbj.ID 107 

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
RM  -2.3087     0.1129  -20.46   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
      Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2   -4.43967    0.13667 -32.485
2|3   -3.63258    0.11504 -31.576
...
19|20  2.36590    0.11028  21.454
```

`str(otp)` returns only one entry for the `$beta` attribute (for `RMem` variable in which I am interested)

```
> str(otp)
...
 $ beta         : Named num -2.31
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "RMem"
...
```

`unlist()` function reveals only the estimate value as well. Could you please advise me how I can extract the `z-value` and `p-value` for the `B estimate` for the `RMem` variable?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `summary(otp)$coefficients[1,c(3,4)]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! I did not realise that summary(otp)$coefficients contains the z-value and p-value for RMem (which are reported in the "Coefficients" field) in the very last row.

Answer (score 0):

So I cannot perfectly replicate using the clmm call as that is new to me but the summary function looks to be returning an item of the same type so this should work with some replacements needed:

```
##with the mtcars dataset

data(mtcars)
glm1<-summary(glm(mpg~cyl+disp+hp,data=mtcars))
glm1$coefficients[,'t value'] #change to z value
glm1$coefficients[,'Pr(>|t|)'] #this will return your t-values - you need to change "t" to "z"

##as a data.frame from a function##
getCoefs<-function(summaryModel){
    sumResults<-data.frame(coefs=names(summaryModel$coefficients[,'t value']),
    t=summaryModel$coefficients[,'t value'],
    prT=summaryModel$coefficients[,'Pr(>|t|)'])
    return(sumResults)
}
sumResults<-getCoefs(glm1)
```